# Unhandled error in debug adapter: SyntaxError: Unexpected token L in JSON at position 0

Tags: android, windows, react-native, visual-studio-code

Error:

```
******** Unhandled error in debug adapter: SyntaxError: Unexpected token L in JSON at position 0    
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:471:28)
```

Hello Guys,

I had found a lot of other issues/questions like this here and any where else, but no of them includes "Unhandled error in debug adapter". I had tried a lot of workflows, but nothing worked.

**Short Introduction:**

OS: Windows 64x

IDE: VS Code (version: 1.25.1 / launch.json see below)

vscode-Plugin: React Native Tools (version: 0.6.12)

Language/Framework: React-Native

(React-version: 16.4.1 /RN-version 0.55.4 / cli-version: 2.0.1)

Project: Android App (iOS followed later)

Output of React-Native: Run android
*Installing APK 'app-debug.apk'* was successful.

Output of React-Native: *Starting custom debugger by executing: echo A debugger is not needed:* "[project-location]" "[project-location].vscode"

Starting App with react-native run-android via terminal still working.

Try following troubleshooting steps:

- comment out all JSON.parse() calls
- check all fetch based functions
- check older repository revisions
- repair vscode
- reinstall vscode
- update RN to 0.56.0
- change mobile device

Existing project is to large to show it here and dosn't exist in a public repo.

**launch.json - I'm using "Debug Android"**

```
{    
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "name": "Debug Android",    
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",    
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",    
            "platform": "android",    
            "sourceMaps": true,    
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react",
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to packager",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "attach",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug in Exponent",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "exponent",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know where the problem is located:

- project
- vscode
- node
- ...

Logcat prints only [INFO] no Warnings and no Errors.

Want to debug project with debug terminal of vscode, because debugging with chrome doesn't work with breakpoints.

I'm very new at working with vscode and RN, please explain possible solutions a little bit more detailed.

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: Complement: 
Debugging with Chrome and breakpoints works now (mostly). 
App runs in Debug- and in Release-mode fine. 
Only Debugging in VS Code is farther not possible.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in the vscode-react-native extension. There's already been a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/pull/760) made to fix this, but if you're feeling adventurous, go to your vscode extensions folder, open the vscode-react-native folder, go to src/debugger/forkedAppWorker.js and replace the following lines:

```
const nodeArgs = [`--inspect=${port}`, "--debug-brk", scriptToRunPath];
```

with

```
const nodeArgs = [`--inspect=${port}`, "--debug-brk"];
```

and

```
this.debuggeeProcess = child_process.spawn("node", nodeArgs, { 
    stdio: ["pipe", "pipe", "pipe", "ipc"], 
})
```

with

```
this.debuggeeProcess = child_process.fork(scriptToRunPath, nodeArgs)
```

For more details see the [actual file change log](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/pull/760/commits/98fd6e570fa12a6fd26431d55e9e9a6b02c224d2) (don't worry about it being .ts vs .js, and don't worry about the other two files being changed).

Comment: Thanks! Extension I have 0.6.13 and the 0.6.14 version isn't showing after I tried to "update" to fix this

Comment: just downgraded from **0.6.14** to **0.6.13** because of [#777](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/777) and then downgraded from **0.6.13** to **0.6.12** because of the issue mentioned here

Comment: many thanks for this answer

new Error comes up: 
Stack: Error: Failed to run the application in Android: Error while executing command C\:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb devices': Command failed: C\:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb devices

at the start of the url is problem with slashes i think, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: FWIW on Windows if you're looking for the path to your vscode extensions folder, it's in %userprofile%\.vscode\extensions (e.g. c:\users\bob\.vscode\extensions)